# I am having an issues with TensorFlow Beginners tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

I recently started interested in deep learning. I have copied the Tensorflow Beginner tutorial  I get the syntax error and can't run the script

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf
x  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)


#TRAINING

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y).reduction_indices = [1]

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

#(SYNTAX ERROR IN "P" OF TRAIN_STEP)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

tf.global_variable_initializer().run()

for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

#EVALUATION

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Why this happens and how to fix it so I can continue with my learnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y).reduction_indices = [1]
```

You should notice that the brackets don't close, this is not a valid statement.

Can you try to recopy the code you found online and carefully check what you copied?

Good luck!

Comment: It did worked!! (though the code given did not have the brackets). Another problem came up was the keyword can't be an expression... but Thanks!!!

Comment: Just solved it !!!! GREAT jajaja know I have to wait 30 min or more for the result :)

Comment: Great! Good luck!